# Python Tkinter horizontal auto scrolling label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Currently, i have this python tkinter label that scroll through the text horizontally.

```
 deli = 100   
 svar = tk.StringVar()
 labl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=svar, height=1,width=20,fg='skyblue',bg='black',font=('calibri',(13)))
def shif():
    shif.msg = shif.msg[1:] + shif.msg[0]
    svar.set(shif.msg)
    root.after(deli, shif)
shif.msg=' This is a Test This is a Test This is a Test'
shif()
```

But i find that the label movement is quite jerky. I think it's because every time it moves  (or shifted rather) by 1 character. Is there any way to get a smoother output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want smoother animation, put the text on a canvas. Doing that will allow you to move the text in as small as one-pixel increments. You can simply insert the entire text screen, then move the object in whatever direction you want and the canvas will manage clipping the text for you.

Comment: You mean to use `canvas.create_text`? It doesn't seems to support `textvariable` command. Sorry if the question sounds stupid.

Comment: @ChrisAung: why do you think you need a textvariable option? You can still change the text whenever you want. Though, if you wanted to you could embed a label in the canvas to get the best of both worlds.